# datatable does not render in Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

The datatable does not render in a  Shinydashboard. It just renders a thin white strip for the box. Running only the datatable  function in  RStudio renders the datatable in the RStudio  viewer. So what the correct way to render a DT datatable in a shiny app?

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(DT)
library(xtable)
source('../ts01/db.R')

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(tableOutput("table1"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(amount_data)
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: As you havent provided the actual table content, my initial guess is that you change source('../ts01/db.R') to source('../ts01/db.R', local=TRUE).

Comment: Also not sure it necessary to call `datatable(amount_data)`, I think if amount_data is a `data.frame` it will do so without the extra command.

Comment: The data comes via source('../ts01/db.R'). This R script uses RMySQl to query a SQL table into a valid data frame.

Comment: In RStudio the a call to datatable(amount_data)  renders the datatable  in the RStudio  viewer. Let's assume it's required for the rendering the data.

Comment: `renderDataTable()` must be paired with `dataTableOutput()` instead of `tableOutput()`

Answer (score 12):

You should try the following:

**1)** `tableOutput`

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
my_data <- head(mtcars)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(tableOutput("table1"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table1 <- renderTable({
    my_data
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**2)** `dataTableOutput`

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinydashboard)

my_data <- head(mtcars)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(DT::dataTableOutput("table1"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(my_data)
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: if you shrink the browser window you will notice that the datatable isn't contained inside the box element. use datatable(my_data, extensions = 'Responsive')

Answer (score 6):

To make sure you use the right package to render your datatable use this in your ui instead:

```
DT::dataTableOutput('table1')
```